# Execute several .sql files in a single transaction using PostgreSQL and bash

Tags: bash, postgresql, transactions

Say I have the files:

```
file1.sql
file2.sql
file3.sql
```

I need all three files to be executed in a single transaction. I'm looking for a bash script like:

```
psql -h hostname -U username dbname -c "
begin;
\i file1.sql
\i file2.sql
\i file3.sql
commit;"
```

This fails with an error: `Syntax error at or near "\"`.

I also tried connecting to the DB first and then executing the fails, like that:

```
psql dbname
begin;
\i file1.sql
\i file2.sql
\i file3.sql
commit;
```

This also fails, because the 'begin' command executes only when the connection is terminated.

Is it possible to execute several .sql files in a single transaction using PostgreSQL and bash?

**Edit:**

The rough structure of each of the files is similar:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'WIN1251';
\i file4.sql
\i file5.sql
<etc>
RESET CLIENT_ENCODING;
```

Comment: you could build a single file to execute cat ing the files together with printf begin+end around

Comment: @amdixon Yes, I could, but each of the files also contain \i commands. So the result is going to be the same.

Comment: do you control (/are you generating) these files ?

Comment: @amdixon The files are automatically generated, I don't control them.

Comment: post the rough structure ( entire if small ) of the sql files

Comment: Either a sub-shell: `(echo "BEGIN;"; cat file1.sql; cat file2.sql; ... echo "COMMIT;") | psql ...` or use a here-document.

Comment: @amdixon I'm not sure if that is what you want, but I've edited the post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either use a sub-shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
 (echo "BEGIN;"; cat file1.sql; cat file2.sql; echo "COMMIT;") \
 | psql -U the_user the_database

#eof
```

or use a here-document:

```
#!/bin/sh
psql -U the_user the_database <<OMG
BEGIN;

\i file1.sql

\i file2.sql

COMMIT;
OMG

#eof
```

NOTE: in HERE-documents there will be no *globbing*, so file*sql will **not** be expanded. Shell-variables will be expanded, even within quotes.

Comment: Yes, the sub-shell works, because of the pipe. Didn't think to pipe the files into psql. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 23):

You can also use the `-1` or `--single-transaction` option to execute all your scripts in a transaction:

```
cat file*.sql | psql -1
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd create new files for the startup (start transaction, set encoding etc) and finish (commit).

Then run something like:

```
cat startup.sql file*.sql finish.sql | psql dbname
```

Comment: I used the first solution, but reckon this one would work either.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, for Windows command line:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %A IN (`dir *.sql /b/a-d`) DO psql -f %A
```