# How connect to database psql?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, macos, psql

I'm trying to create and connect db using PostgreSQL and this SQLfile:

```
-- recreate the user --
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "playground" from student;
REASSIGN OWNED BY student TO postgres;
DROP DATABASE playground WITH (FORCE);
DROP USER student;
CREATE USER student WITH PASSWORD '1';

-- recreate the database --
CREATE DATABASE playground OWNER student;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "playground" TO student;

-- fulfill the database --
-- \connect playground student
\connect "dbname=playground user=student password=1"

BEGIN;
\i sql/schema.sql
\i sql/data.sql
COMMIT;
```

But when I try to run it using JDBC / IntelliJ idea I have an error

> syntax error at or near \

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537204/execute-several-sql-files-in-a-single-transaction-using-postgresql-and-bash

Comment: `psql` is not a database. Postgres is the database. The `psql` tool is a native app that connects to the Postgres database server to give you a command-line interface. This avenue has nothing to do with Java. An alternative avenue is JDBC, for connecting to the Postgres database from within a Java app. This avenue has nothing to do with the *psql* tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\i` and co are commands that the [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) tool processes. The Postgres [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) doesn't understand such commands.

You have two options.

### Do those commands in Java

`\connect` is done by dropping your [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) Connection (`close()` it), then create a new connection by crafting a JDBC URL with the right dbname and user/pass properties.

`\i` is done by opening the file and reading each line (using e.g. `BufferedReader` or `Files.lines`), then sending each line to PSQL by creating a `Statement` and executing it.

### Use process exec

You can also use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to fire up the actual `psql` command, passing it this script by getting the standard-in of the `psql` processes you start, sending these lines to `/usr/bin/psql` or where-ever it is. You'll need to know where `psql` lives to do this, which is not neccessarily easy.